# Firebase's onSnapshot inside a useEffect; why does this infinitely loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting documents from a collection in Firebase and I was wondering if the following useEffect would loop. Is this good practice?

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const routineRef = collection(db, "routines", session?.user?.id!, currentRoutine.name);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(routineRef, (docsSnap) => {
      setWeightsHistorySnapshot(docsSnap.docs);
      // Infinite loop because this fills up my console
      console.log("Current data: ", docsSnap.docs);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [weightsHistorySnapshot, currentRoutine.name, session?.user?.id]);
```

Comment: What happens if you run the code?  You could certainly observe for yourself how it behaves.

Comment: @DougStevenson it gets into an infinite loop. See edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

> An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document.

You set the state using `setWeightsHistorySnapshot`, and have `weightsHistorySnapshot` in your dependencies array, which in turn changes on every call. This causes the hook to run over and over.